# How do I serve protected videos from cloudfront

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to serve private video content over RTMP, accessible only through a signed url

Here are my CloudFront distribution settings:

```
Origin Domain Name : ct.recorder.s3.amazonaws.com   

Restrict Bucket Access : Yes

Origin Access Identity : Use an Existing Identity

Your Identities : CT rtmp videos

Grant Read Permissions on Bucket : No, I Will Update Permissions

Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs) : Yes

Trusted Signers : Self

Distribution State : Enabled
```

When I try a signed cloudfront url, it'll fail to play.

Am I missing something?

I'm using the SDK to programmatically upload the video files, so I have control over the permissions I can set. Do I have to make a CannedACL or something?

On the bucket level, I made a policy file:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EF5LIV7LW3XE4"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ct.recorder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However it still doesn't work. I still can't access my videos

I tried `rtmpdump` and that failed with a `NetStream.Failed`

### EDIT:

I got the free edition of Cloudberry for S3, and I went into the bucket and the objects in the bucket and set permissions so that the `Origin access identity` can `read`.

The result is that `CloudFront Origin Access Identity EF5LIV7LW3XE4` has `Open/download` permissions on the object of the bucket, and it has `list` permissions for the bucket itself.

But that didn't help. rtmpdump and the player still return errors.

### EDIT:

I've tried editing the policy, but when I change it to what Michael suggests, save it, and view it again, my policy does not have my edits in it.

### EDIT:

It's not that I can't edit the policy, it's that AWS auto-corrects the "CanonicalUser" to "AWS", and sets the values appropriately.

So now I'm confused. The documentation says I need "CanonicalUser", but AWS won't let me do it.

### EDIT:

After getting [official confirmation from the forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141606&tstart=0) that it does indeed auto-correct, I'll assume that my S3 bucket policy is correct, and that the problem is elsewhere. Perhaps with the library I'm using to sign my keys.

### EDIT:

I tried using Cloudberry Explorer to create a signed cloudfront url, using my private key and `access ID`, but that url wouldn't work for either my player or `rtmpdump`.

### EDIT:

I got confirmation that the node package that I was using to create signed urls wasn't compatible with rtmp urls. Is there a node package that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signed URL was the problem. The node package I was using couldn't do rtmp urls. Once I switched to using the official sdk for .net, I could play my content. The package has since been updated to work with rtmp urls.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Principal": {
     "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EF5LIV7LW3XE4"
},
```

Almost certainly not what you want.

```
"Principal":{
  "CanonicalUser":"79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2bexample"
},
```

> To specify an origin access identity, use the value of Amazon S3 Canonical User ID on the Origin Access Identity **page** in the CloudFront console
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-granting-permissions-to-oai (emphasis added)</sup>

On the left side of the screen, under "Private Content," the value you need is under "Origin Access Identity" is where you'll find that string of hex digits.

Comment: On the S3 Permissions page, I click on `Edit bucket policy`, and then try to change the policy to what you suggest. I hit save to close the box, and then save on the "Permissions" page, but when I look at the policy again, it reverted to what it was. It won't let me edit the policy

Comment: No idea, although I would suggest making a copy of the bucket policy, then trying to just delete it, then create a new one... and if you're doing this with a 3rd party tool, I'd do it in the AWS console instead.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. It appears as just a blank text box after I save it and go back in. I'm doing this with the AWS console.

Comment: I found that I can edit my policy just fine. The actual problem is that it's auto-correcting out the `CanonicalUser` entry and replacing it with the `AWS` entry, with the value pointing to the Identity ID.

I still can't access my videos, though.

Comment: I spent some time on the official forums and found that [it does, in fact, auto-correct](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=508842&#508842), and so the two values `AWS` and `CanonicalUser` are equivalent. Good to know! But I'm still stumped on what's borked